# How to add values to list from Object using stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a Object with multiple properties and I want to add multiple properties to same list

I was able to add one property couldn't find a way to add other property.

Can we do that if yes how ?

```
List<MyObject> myObject = new ArrayList<>();

I have some values in the object  here 

List<Long> Ids  = myObject .stream().map(MyObject::getJobId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here I want to add one more property from same MyObject object getTestId to the list is there a way that I can add with in the same above statement ?

Comment: `List<Long> Ids=myObject.stream().flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.getJobId(), o.getTestId())) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

Create two lists using the streams then combine them in the end, map can only return one value either `getJobId` or `getTestId`, so you can't do it in the same iteration.

```java
    List<Long> JobIds = myObject.stream().map(myObj::getJobId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Long> TestIds = myObject.stream().map(myObj::getTestId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Long> Ids = Stream.concat(JobIds.stream(), TestIds.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list containing the jobIds and the testIds then you can use something like this:

```java
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
myObject.forEach(o -> { 
    ids.add(o.getJobId());
    ids.add(o.getTestId()); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In `.map` operation the object should be mapped to a list/stream of required ids and then apply `flatMap`:

```java
List<Long> ids = myObject
        .stream()
        .map(mo -> Arrays.asList(mo.getId(), mo.getTestId()))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or (same as Holger's comment)

```java
List<Long> ids = myObject
        .stream()
        .flatMap(mo -> Stream.of(mo.getId(), mo.getTestId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If the `id`s should be followed by `testId`s, the streams may be concatenated:

```java
List<Long> ids = Stream.concat(
    myObject.stream().map(MyObject::getId),
    myObject.stream().map(MyObject::getTestId)
)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If more than two properties should be listed one after another, `Stream.of` + `flatMap` should be used:

```java
List<Long> ids = Stream.of(
    myObject.stream().map(MyObject::getId),
    myObject.stream().map(MyObject::getTestId),
    myObject.stream().map(MyObject::getAnotherId)
)
.flatMap(Function.identity())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```